Backtrader Multiple TP levels sometimes don't work
I have a major bug which makes strange orders on wrong prices. Sometimes even double or a sell order is missing.
How can I get the logic working?

Entry via RSI (no issues)
StopLoss 5%
TakeProfit 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%
SL moves to break even (+5%) after first TP level hit

The problem just shows up sometimes, depends on the assets like ACM and more (see the results).
I tried different timeframes, like 4h, 1d, etc.
I use multiple assets and filtered just ACM for this example.
Strategy code:
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import backtrader as bt
import matplotlib as plt
import backtrader.analyzers as btanalyzers
import backtrader.indicators as btind
from datetime import datetime
%matplotlib inline

class Strategy(bt.Strategy):
    params = (
        ('rsi_period', 14),
        )
    
    def __init__(self):
      self.broker.set_coc(False) #Cheat on Close
      self.rsi = {}
      self.returns = []
      self.trades = dict()
      self.available_cash = 0

      for i, d in enumerate(self.datas):
        self.rsi[d] = bt.ind.RSI(d.close, period=self.params.rsi_period)
        self.trades[d] = dict()
        self.trades[d] = {"stage": 0, "units" : 0.0, "pos_price" : 0.0, "buy_executed" : False}

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        """ Logging function fot this strategy"""
        dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
        print(f'{self.datas[0].datetime.date(0).isoformat()}, {txt}')

    def notify_order(self, order):
        """ Triggered upon changes to orders. """
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            if order.isbuy():
                self.log(f'[{order.data._name}] BUY EXECUTED, Price: {order.executed.price:.2f}, Cost: {order.executed.value:.2f}, Size: {order.executed.size}, PnL: {order.executed.pnl}, pprice: {order.executed.pprice}')
            elif order.issell():
                self.log(f'[{order.data._name}] SELL EXECUTED, Price: {order.executed.price:.2f}, Cost: {order.executed.value:.2f}, Size: {order.executed.size}, PnL: {order.executed.pnl}, pprice: {order.executed.pprice}')
            #Reset pending buy order var
            data = order.data
            if data in self.trades:
                self.trades[data]["buy_executed"] = False

    def next(self):
        self.available_cash = self.broker.get_cash()
        for i, d in enumerate(self.datas):
            if len(d) > self.params.rsi_period:  # Ensure enough data points for RSI calculation
                if self.getposition(d).size == 0 and not self.trades[d]["buy_executed"]:
                    if self.rsi[d] > 70: #Entry Cond
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 1
                        self.trades[d]["units"] = d.target / d.close[0]
                        self.buy(data=d, price=d.close[0], size=self.trades[d]["units"], exectype=bt.Order.Limit)  #buy position
                        self.trades[d]["buy_executed"] = True
                        break

                if self.getposition(d).size > 0:
                    #Multiple Take Profit levels
                    pos_price = self.getposition(d).price
                    pos_units = self.trades[d]["units"]
                    tp_level4 = pos_price * (1 + 1.00)
                    tp_level3 = pos_price * (1 + 0.75)
                    tp_level2 = pos_price * (1 + 0.50)
                    tp_level1 = pos_price * (1 + 0.25)
                    sl_level  = pos_price * (1 - 0.05)

                    if self.trades[d]["stage"] >= 2:
                        sl_level  = pos_price * (1 + 0.05)

                    #Stop Loss
                    if d.low[0] <= sl_level:
                        self.sell(data=d, price=sl_level, size=self.getposition(d).size, exectype=bt.Order.Market)
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 0

                    #Take Profit
                    if self.trades[d]["stage"] == 1 and d.high[0] >= tp_level1:
                        self.sell(data=d, price=tp_level1, size=pos_units*0.25, exectype=bt.Order.Limit)
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 2
                    if self.trades[d]["stage"] == 2 and d.high[0] >= tp_level2:
                        self.sell(data=d, price=tp_level2, size=pos_units*0.25, exectype=bt.Order.Limit)
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 3
                    if self.trades[d]["stage"] == 3 and d.high[0] >= tp_level3:
                        self.sell(data=d, price=tp_level3, size=pos_units*0.25, exectype=bt.Order.Limit)
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 4
                    if self.trades[d]["stage"] == 4 and d.high[0] >= tp_level4:
                        self.sell(data=d, price=tp_level4, size=self.getposition(d).size, exectype=bt.Order.Limit) #use current position size to make sure no micro values are left
                        self.trades[d]["stage"] = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    ordersize   = 100
    com_perc    = 0.08

    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    file = 'ACM-USDT.csv'
    full_path = os.path.join('/content/', file)
    symbol    = file.split('-')[0]
    ticker    = symbol+'-USDT'
    df = pd.read_csv(full_path)
    #format datetime
    df['open_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open_time'])
    df.set_index('open_time', inplace=True)
    data = bt.feeds.PandasData(
        fromdate=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
        dataname=df,
        name=ticker,
        datetime=None,
        open=0,
        high=1,
        low=2,
        close=3,
        volume=4,
        openinterest=5,
        )
    data.target = ordersize
    cerebro.adddata(data, name=ticker)

    cerebro.addstrategy(Strategy)
    cerebro.broker.setcash(1000)  # Set initial cash
    cerebro.broker.setcommission(commission=(com_perc/100))  # Set commission

    # Execute
    results = cerebro.run()

    #Plot
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 10]
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
    cerebro.plot(iplot = False, )

Results of orders:
2023-02-24, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.84, Cost: 99.73, Size: 35.092593269533054, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.8418083333333333
2023-03-03, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.57, Cost: 99.73, Size: -35.092593269533054, PnL: -9.408616693839052, pprice: 0.0
2023-03-08, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.57, Cost: 98.85, Size: 38.467333220068404, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.569729166666667
2023-03-10, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.37, Cost: 98.85, Size: -38.467333220068404, PnL: -7.549374424993514, pprice: 0.0
2023-03-21, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.44, Cost: 99.65, Size: 40.896032062489134, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.436745833333333
2023-04-08, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 3.29, Cost: 24.91, Size: -10.224008015622283, PnL: 8.759717067618185, pprice: 2.436745833333333
2023-05-11, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.52, Cost: 74.74, Size: -30.672024046866852, PnL: 2.7016941181281804, pprice: 0.0
2023-05-20, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.36, Cost: 98.73, Size: 41.87787365096537, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.3575541666666666
2023-05-24, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.26, Cost: 98.73, Size: -41.87787365096537, PnL: -3.951875343529434, pprice: 0.0
2023-05-26, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.27, Cost: 99.67, Size: 43.83513605330353, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.273658333333333
2023-06-05, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.12, Cost: 99.67, Size: -43.83513605330353, PnL: -6.802482529871805, pprice: 0.0
2023-06-17, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 1.85, Cost: 99.83, Size: 54.082557023296054, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 1.8458166666666667
2023-07-27, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.94, Cost: 24.96, Size: -13.520639255824014, PnL: 14.831352559682347, pprice: 1.8458166666666667
2023-07-27, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.94, Cost: 24.96, Size: -13.520639255824014, PnL: 14.831352559682347, pprice: 1.8458166666666667
2023-08-18, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 1.94, Cost: 49.91, Size: -27.041278511648024, PnL: 2.414560827102568, pprice: 0.0
2023-08-20, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 2.02, Cost: 98.80, Size: 49.02060908106783, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 2.0155791666666665
2023-08-22, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 1.94, Cost: 98.80, Size: -49.02060908106783, PnL: -3.921648726485419, pprice: 0.0
2023-08-29, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 1.96, Cost: 100.00, Size: 50.983341193265105, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 1.961425
2023-09-11, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 1.84, Cost: 100.00, Size: -50.983341193265105, PnL: -6.246946310293119, pprice: 0.0
2023-09-15, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 1.85, Cost: 99.67, Size: 53.814796378264205, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 1.8521791666666667
2023-09-25, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 1.76, Cost: 99.67, Size: -53.814796378264205, PnL: -5.017332849000175, pprice: 0.0
2023-10-03, [ACM-USDT] BUY EXECUTED, Price: 1.77, Cost: 99.61, Size: 56.19924505680808, PnL: 0.0, pprice: 1.7725083333333334
2024-02-17, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.25, Cost: 24.90, Size: -14.04981126420202, PnL: 6.7113021365079675, pprice: 1.7725083333333334
2024-03-08, [ACM-USDT] SELL EXECUTED, Price: 2.67, Cost: 24.90, Size: -14.04981126420202, PnL: 12.596592452441383, pprice: 1.7725083333333334

Look at 2023-07-27: here are 2 orders on same price. This is hard to understand, since TP level have a limit price order.

Edit:
Code Changed to minimal executable version as requested.
simply add csv file from down below.
ACM-USDT.csv: Get it from pastebin
Solution:
Usually I get wrong results once I feed backtrader with multiple assets because every asset have different time range it's make it impossible to backtest all together. Only if your format you data that every asset have same start and enddate.
Even if you do so it's seems that backtrader have some more bugs to fix, because it start to buy a assets mutliple times with only one buy order. I tried fix it with a logic to only set one buy order until order is filled. But the bug is deeper in the source code.
So my solution is to run backtrader only with one asset/dataset and loop it. Copy every result to a big dataset and summary the total results together.
Furthermore I used next_open() instead next() function. This require  bt.Cerebro(cheat_on_open=True)
It's helpful to fill your orders on the same candle and was the better way for my purpose. I hope I could help with this information for those, that have similar problems, happy coding!

Pleas add a minimal reproducable example (input, output, expected output).

@MrSmith42 I just added a minimal version and the basic logic of the Multiple TP in the post.
Principally I want 4 TP levels + SL that moves.
You can see the Output in the results above. Some level get hit some are missing or excuted twice on same price.

I figured out that Backtrader can't process correctly 2 sell orders in one data point.
For example: if 2 TP levels get triggert, it set the first sell order once execute it set the second sell which get filled on next data point (candle) with a wrong price level (probably open price of the current data point)
So you need to make sure to set a logic with only one sell order. In case multiple levels get triggert in one candle you need to summery both positions to one and calculate the right tp price + position size.
I will update it on my post later
